# Unable to reinstall fail2ban after completly removing it from Centos 7

Tags: security, installation, centos7, fail2ban, reinstall

After completely removing Fail2ban from Centos 7, I decided to reinstall it.
So I run the installation(yum), and everything seems ok, no errors, But the it seems like the installation does not create any directory in "/etc/fail2ban", and when I run `sudo systemctl start fail2ban` i receive no errors, and it seems like its running, however there are no config files... And it's the same version as before.

I installed it by running:
`sudo yum install fail2ban`
The same command i used to install it in the first place.
And removed it by:
`sudo systemctl stop fail2ban`
`sudo yum remove fail2ban`
And then:
`rm -rf /etc/fail2ban /etc/init.d/fail2ban /var/run/fail2ban /usr/share/doc/fail2ban /usr/local/bin/fail2ban* /usr/lib*/python*/site-packages/fail2ban /usr/local/lib*/python*/site-packages/fail2ban`

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some additional fail2ban-packages, like fail2ban-systemd, fail2ban-server, fail2ban-firewalld etc.

It's possible those are the packages where the configuration files come from, so you may have to reinstall all fail2ban-* packages, as well.

Comment: Thanks you! i ran `yum remove fail2ban\*` and it removed the additional packages and I was able to reinstall it again.

Comment: anyone know what the equivalent would be with apt-get?

Comment: using this yum remove fail2ban\* did the trick for me. Have been struggling for hours why fail2ban would not reinstall the conf files in the /etc/fail2ban folder. I manually remove the /etc/fail2ban folder.